# Como manipular ArrayList de objetos Java

Tags: java

O programa consiste em adicionar alunos e, para cada aluno adicionar disciplinas e, para cada disciplina adicionar notas. No fim o programa deve retornar todos os alunos e suas disciplinas, sendo que para cada disciplina deverá ser mostrada a média, desvio padrão e variância. Primeiramente eu criei duas classes `Aluno` e `Disciplina` e um classe `Aluno1` que faz o uso da classe `Aluno`. Na classe `Aluno`eu criei o atributo `nome` e um `ArrayList` do tipo `Disciplina`. As minhas Dúvidas são:

1 - Como eu crio o método `getDisciplina`, sendo que o atributo é um `ArrayList`?

2 - Como eu acesso os atributos e métodos através do método `getDisciplina` (se é que eu posso fazer isso)?

3 - Como eu acesso os como eu atribuo valores para os objetos que eu crio na classe `Aluno1`?

Eu sei que poderia utilizar diretamente a classe `Disciplina` no programa, porém não quero fazer dessa maneira.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aluno {
private String nome;
private ArrayList<Disciplina> disciplinas;

//Construtor nome
public Aluno(String nome){
    this.nome = nome;

    disciplinas = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();
}
public String getNome(){
    return nome;
}

public Disciplina getDisciplina(){
    for(Disciplina item : disciplinas) {
        return item;
    }
    return null;
}
}







import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aluno1{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
    int opcao, opcao2;

    do{
        System.out.println("0 - Sair\n1 - Adicionar novo aluno\n2 - Mostrar todos os alunos");
        opcao = input.nextInt();

        switch(opcao){
            case 0:

                break;

            case 1:

                System.out.println("Nome do aluno: ");
                String nome = input.next();

                Aluno aluno = new Aluno(nome);
                alunos.add(aluno);

                do{
                    System.out.println("0 - Sair\n1 - Adicionar Disciplina");
                    opcao2 = input.nextInt();

                    switch(opcao2){
                        case 0:

                            break;

                        case 1:

                            System.out.println("Nome da disciplina: ");
                            String nomeDisc = input.next();

                            aluno.getDisciplina().;

                            break;

                        default:

                            System.out.println("Opcão Inválida!");
                            break;  
                    }
                }while(opcao2 != 0);

                break;

            case 2:

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Opcão Inválida!");

                break;
        }
    }while(opcao != 0);
}
}







import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Disciplina {
private String nome;
private ArrayList<Double> notas;

public String getNome(){
    return nome;
}

public Disciplina(String nome){
    this.nome = nome;

    notas = new ArrayList<Double>();
}

public ArrayList<Double> getNota(){
    return notas;
}

public double getMedia(){
    double media = 0;

    for(Double nota : notas){
        media += nota;
    }

    if(media != 0)
        return media / notas.size();
    else
        return (double) 0;
}

public double getDesvioPadrao(){
    double soma = 0;

    for(Double nota : notas) {
        soma += Math.pow((nota - getMedia()), 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt((soma / (notas.size() - 1)));
}

public double getVariancia(){
    double soma = 0;

    for(Double nota : notas) {
        soma += Math.pow((nota - getMedia()), 2);
    }

    return soma / (notas.size() - 1);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Eu creio que você deveria ter o `getter` para a lista, `getDisciplinas()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Como eu crio o método getDisciplina, sendo que o atributo é um ArrayList?

Simples, faça ele retornar um `ArrayList` de `Disciplina`, já que cada aluno terá mais de uma disciplina. Ex:

```
public ArrayList<Disciplina> getDisciplinas() {
    return disciplinas;
}
```

> 2 - Como eu acesso os atributos e métodos através do método getDisciplina (se é que eu posso fazer isso)?

Você precisa acessar a lista de disciplinas pelo seu índice:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
// para setar um atributo através do setter
aluno.getDisciplinas().get(indice).setNome(nomeDisciplina);

//para pegar um atributo através do getter ou realizar operações
String nomeDisciplina = aluno.getDisciplinas().get(indice).getNome();
double media = aluno.getDisciplinas().get(indice).getMedia();
```

> 3 - Como eu acesso ou como eu atribuo valores para os objetos que eu crio na classe Aluno1?

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno("Irineu");
aluno.getDisciplinas().add(new Disciplina("Matemática").getNotas().add(9));
double media = aluno.getDisciplinas().get(indice).getMedia();
```

Fiz dessa maneira acima porque você disse que "não queria usar diretamente a classe `Disciplina`". Por não querer usar, acredito que você não queira instanciar um objeto de `Disciplina` e por isso foi utilizado direto no construtor. Porém fica mais legível dessa forma:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno("Irineu");
Disciplina disciplina = new Disciplina("Matemática");
disciplina.getNotas().add(9);
aluno.getDisciplinas().add(disciplina);

double media = aluno.getDisciplinas().get(indice).getMedia();
```

Talvez essas sejam suas dúvidas. Qualquer coisa eu atualizo a reposta.